# Conditionally installing importlib on python2.6

Tags: python, dependencies, dependency-management, import

I have a python library that has a dependency on `importlib`. `importlib` is in the standard library in Python 2.7, but is a third-party package for older pythons. I typically keep my dependencies in a pip-style requirements.txt. Of course, if I put `importlib` in here, it will fail if installed on 2.7. How can I conditionally install importlib only if it's not available in the standard lib?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with pip and a single requirements file. I can think of two options I'd choose from:

### Multiple requirements files

Create a base.txt file that contains most of your packages:

```
# base.txt
somelib1
somelib2
```

And create a requirements file for python 2.6:

```
# py26.txt
-r base.txt
importlib
```

and one for 2.7:

```
# py27.txt
-r base.txt
```

### Requirements in setup.py

If your library has a setup.py file, you can check the version of python, or just check if the library already exists, like this:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
install_requires = ['somelib1', 'somelib2']

try:
    import importlib
except ImportError:
    install_requires.append('importlib')

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_requires,
    ...
)
```

Comment: I ended up using multiple requirements files. Thanks.

Comment: Question...  How does this interact with pip?  Does pip just iterate over the items in "install_requires"?  If so, can you just include the version of the lib in the list?  For example ['somelib1==1.02',]

Comment: @DavidS yes, you can put the version dependency in ``install_requires``