# Conditional pip install requirements on Heroku for Django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

Let me start by saying, that I don't think there is a way to do this...  but, there are a lot of clever people out there and so I thought I would ask!  :)

I found a good article/post by Randall Degges on [setting up a Django app on Heroku](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html) ([Internet Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140413201552/http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html)).  I really like what he has to say about breaking your requirements up into different files (common.txt, dev.txt, prod.txt etc).

This works great on Heroku for production, but I also maintain a Dev/QA site on Heroku, and I have a few packages that I don't really need for prod that I do use for Dev/QA.  The best example is django-debug-toolbar.  Currently, I do have this in my production requirements.txt, and I dynamically decide if I need to add it to my installed apps, etc in settings.py at runtime by looking at the DEBUG setting.

Which works fine... but, it would be great if I could not even bother about installing it in prod.  I guess what I sort of want is for pip to be able to take a requirements file that allows for conditionals includes (why couldn't it just take a python file?) or for Heroku to support a config setting that tells it which requirements file to use.  Has anyone found a way of accomplishing this?  Or is it just wishful thinking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked into [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)?

*If your Python application contains a setup.py file but excludes a requirements.txt file, python setup.py develop will be used to install your package and resolve your dependencies.
This works best with distribute or setuptools. Projects that use distutils directly will be installed, but not linked. The module won’t get updated until there’s a version bump.
If you already have a requirements file but would like to utilize this feature, you can add the following to your requirements file:*

```
-e .
```

and then follow on the recommendations in [Conditionally installing importlib on python2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418064/conditionally-installing-importlib-on-python2-6)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did review that.  I guess I'm not sure how pip and the setup.py interact, etc.  I did post a comment/question on the SO question that you linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar needs in buildout and implemented it there.
Now that I am migrating from buildout to pip, I came out with this script to use some various requirements files based on some conditions, that can based on os/arch or some environment variable or anything you like. Crude but effective for me.

See https://gist.github.com/pombredanne/72130ee6f202e89c13bb

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's wishful thinking. The pip requirements file is very simple. Literally, all pip does is just prepend `pip install` to each line in the file, so conditionals and such are a no-go. Having separate requirement files for each environment is a nice idea, but the question becomes why not just have a version for your Dev/QA site as well?

That said, I think this is all a bit academic anyways. Simply having a package installed doesn't hurt anything. For instance, it doesn't matter if you have the django-debug-toolbar package installed even in production, your production instance won't actually *use* it, so aside from the few kilobytes of drive space it takes up, it's not a problem.

Personally, I always just have one requirements file, and in there, I only put *requirements*, i.e. these are packages that the site literally cannot run without. Things like django-debug-toolbar, ipython, etc. I just install manually when I need them.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  To answer your question, I can have a separate file for each.  But, Heroku only looks for a file that named requirements.txt.  So, if you have two environments with them, then there really isn't a good way control what gets pip installed into each one.  And you are correct that it's not a huge deal, but the more things you have in the requirements.txt the slower it is to load your app or spawn additional dynos etc.  Again, not a huge deal.  But, it's preferable to have it be as lean as possible.

Comment: Well, again, the best solution IMHO is to simply only put true requirements in your requirements file. Even in development, django-debug-toolbar and such is not a *requirement*, and it doesn't make sense to force it to be installed when a particular developer may not want to use it.

Comment: I agree - mostly :)  But, if you have conditional imports in your in your settings file (like I do) then it seems like you should not leave future developers guessing about what is "required" for those particular options.  Ideally, I could have one environ variable to would control turning on/off a set of functionality (and would handle making sure pip installed what was needed).  Again, it's not critical.  Just hoping to maybe learn something new today.  If Heroku had a way of configuring the requirements.txt file for an app/env, that would work like a charm.

Comment: That's why you use developer-specific settings files. I have dev, staging, and prod directories and under dev, a directory for each developer. Then, you just symlink the active directory to something like "local" and have settings.py import local.settings. That way each dev can have a completely customized environment instead of having to share one "dev" settings file, which is pretty much impossible if you have developers using different OSes and such.

Comment: Yes; I've used that methodology before, but I don't want those to be checked into git and then pushed to Heroku and production.  Do you use Heroku?  Or do you manage your own platform?  The main way that you interact with Heroku is that you push from your git repo and then you have config vars that you can set via the commandline.  That's fine for most things and you can set an env flag and then configure how you want.  But, it's a bit more difficult when it comes to your requirements file.  Because, AFAIK, it only will read requirements.txt in your apps folder.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're developing on Windows and want to use Gunicorn and psycopg2 in production (e.g. Heroku) but can't in dev. Conditional is obviously better for this.