# Can you set conditional dependencies for Python 2 and 3 in setuptools?

Tags: python, dependency-management, setuptools

When releasing a Python egg with support for both Python 2 and 3, can you specify dependencies that change depending on which version you're using? For example, if you use `dnspython` for Python 2, there is a Python 3 version that is called `dnspython3`.

Can you write your `setuptools.setup()` function in such a way that your egg is useable to both versions if that is the only roadblock, i.e., if you have run `2to3` to ensure that the rest of your library is compatible with both versions.

I have looked through these documents and can't seem to find the answer this question:

- [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html)
- [setuptools' Declaring Dependencies](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies)
- [Travis CI Python documentation](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/python/)
- [pip Requirements Files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#requirements-files)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question correctly, but can't you just query the Python version in ``setup.py`` (via ``sys.version_info``) and feed different dependency sets to ``setup()`` depending on the result?

Comment: I thought of that earlier and forgot to mention it. I don't know that this solution would solve the related problem of Travis seeing the dependency change, since it relies on pip's requirements files. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: I do not know much about Travis, but ``pip`` generates requirements by running ``setup.py``, so if Travis gets the requirements file with the same Python version it is going to use for installation, this solution will work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Bogdan's comment helped point me on my way. I thought I'd post what I did in case anyone else has my problem.

For the example in the question, I did exactly what Bogdan suggested:

### setup.py

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    dnspython = "dnspython"
elif sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    dnspython = "dnspython3"

setup(
    ... <snip> ...
    install_requires=[
        "%s >= 1.10.0" % dnspython,
    ]
)
```

However, this still has the issue of pip-style dependencies for Travis and `tox` (I'm not sure why, given Bogdan's second comment). To work around this problem, I created two extra requirements files, as shown below:

### requirements-py2.txt

```
dnspython>=1.10.0
```

### requirements-py3.txt

```
dnspython3>=1.10.0
```

Then for Travis, I made use of some environment variables that I gleaned from the [tornado .travis.yml](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/b3520e5ded5a31c4ab8a96eea63304b1c64c2f7c/.travis.yml):

### .travis.yml

```yaml
install:
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 2* ]]; then pip install -r requirements-py2.txt --use-mirrors; fi
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 3* ]]; then pip install -r requirements-py3.txt --use-mirrors; fi
```

Lastly, for `tox`, I had to use a rather hackish method of using these multiple requirements files.

### tox.ini

```
[testenv:py27]
deps = -rrequirements-py2.txt

[testenv:py33]
deps = -rrequirements-py3.txt
```

Comment: It somehow boils down to the same question again and again: How to do dependency management in python at all ....

Answer (score 4):

The setup.py portion of the answer by @Harold did not work for me: pip install distribution.whl still installs the dependency that the if code says it shouldn't. I will further update this answer in a few days when I have this issue resolved.

Here are some links that may provide additional ways to deal with this ():

- [Wheel docs section explaining conditional dependencies](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#defining-conditional-dependencies): not completely clear but gives a hint of what to do
- [Example on github](https://gist.github.com/petermelias/8481395)
- [Blog post](https://hynek.me/articles/conditional-python-dependencies/)

Comment: I use the solution I gave above here, feel free to check it out: https://github.com/michaelherold/pyIsEmail

Comment: This is the actual proper answer nowadays, see [Environment Markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) available in pip 6.0+(https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/2134).

Comment: For posterity, in case the links change:

"mypackage; python_version<'3.3'",

Answer (score 1):

For something mostly related but not exactly to the point see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078063/302521 and this script: https://gist.github.com/pombredanne/72130ee6f202e89c13bb