# pip wheel conditional dependencies

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

While working on a virtualenv for developing a python package, I use to issue a "pip wheel ." to generate all wheel archives needed for the package.
I start using conditional dependencies by listing them in the setuptools extras_require parameter. Is it possible to generage the wheel archives of a specific conditional dependency?

Something like: pip wheel ".[conditional_feature]" is not supported. (at least on python-2.7)
Note that I can install these dependencies in the virtualenv with: pip install -e ".[conditional_feature]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078063/302521)  and [this script](https://gist.github.com/pombredanne/72130ee6f202e89c13bb) that helps you doing exactly that with a different approach using multiple requirements files and a condition to use one or the other.

### **Update**

Note also that with the latest version (2017) of the pypa trio (pip,setuptools, wheel) you can now use conditional requirements directly. Here is an example with extra_requires that install [various versions of lxml](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/blob/f8132b344ba3a700907c41038e3d663002bbac63/setup.py#L190) on different OSes:

```
extras_require={
        ':platform_system == "Windows"': ['lxml == 3.6.0'],
        ':platform_system == "Linux"': ['lxml == 3.6.4'],
        ':platform_system == "Darwin"': ['lxml == 3.6.4'],

},
```

You can do a lot more than this of course with even more complex expressions.